# How to implement 2/2 multi-signature transactions with bitcoinj

Tags: multi-signature, bitcoinj, implementation

I am using bitcoinj to implement a 2/2 multi-signature transaction. Now I  want to use bitcoinj to generate a 2/2 multi-signature address and its corresponding Redeem Script through the public keys of the two parties, and  to perform sequential signatures between the two parties. I didn't find a similar example in the description document of bitcoinj. Can you give me a specific implementation?

Comment: Any special reason why you want to use bitcoinj? Eletrum might be easier for multisig...